# Find an example of a decreasing function which's derivation is a non-monotone function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, solution-verification

I would say a good example for this is $f(x)=-x$ it is a decreasing function because $x_1<x_2 \implies f(x_1)>f(x_2)$

And the derivation is a constant function $f'(x)=-1$ and not a monotone function

Are there more interesting examples of this?

Thanks

Comment: Constant functions are monotonic (but not strictly). As a hint for a counterexample look for example at some very simple polynomial functions

Comment: So an actual example would be $f(x)=-x^3$ ?

Comment: Yes, that works

Comment: Another question about monotony: Are all surjective non-injective functions not monotonic? Like for example $x^2$

Comment: No, take for example $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ with $f(x)=x$ for $x<0$, $f(x)=0$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $f(x)=x-1$ for $x>1$

Comment: Hmmm... I see thanks!